# Cloth won't collide with collision object? But worked with a cube?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

Ive watched all the tutorials but clearly Im missing something on how cloth collisions work -

Im trying to make clothing, so I have my collision object (body) and cloth plane (subdivided many times) setup:

[image]

Body is collision object:

[image]
And plane is cloth:

[image]

Yet I press play, nothing happens. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Do you play from frame #1 ?
Your actual simulation is set to play from frame #1 to #250.  If you play a different frame range, the simulation won't be computed.

Comment: Yes I move the timeline to 1